# Output of adding an integer and a String in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was asked what the following simple query would return.

```
Select 5 + '4'
```

As, 4 is string type, I expect the query to throw an error. I found I was wrong, tested it, and the result was 9. How does it return the sum?

Comment: It is converted to a number and an error only occurs if this fails.

Comment: Note that its a product specific behavior. (ANSI SQL doesn't allow it.)

Comment: Since the operation is addition '4' would be added to 5 and so on. Now 5 is the first operand and it determines its type to be int. Although next operand is a string it tries to convert it to the type of first operand and since it is able to it adds both and gives 9 as the result. if the second operand contained non-numeric character conversion would fail and you would get error.

Comment: Change '4' to a string containing characters

Comment: I don't understand what there is to ask here. 'How it returns the sum' is very clear - it just converts the string to a number - as a decision by MS. The only useful question would be 'Is this required by/legal in standard ANSI SQL?' But as written, this just seems to be a tautology. @TheShooter It is false that "it tries to convert it to the type of first operand"; binary operators have no preference between their left and right operands; rather, as the accepted answer states, it is the _precedence_ of operands, totally regardless of their order, that determines the direction of type coercion

Comment: @underscore_d thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you mix data types such as `INT` and `VARCHAR`, SQL Server will always attempt to convert everything to [the one that has the highest precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309).

Answer (score 5):

Int will have an implicit conversion, however, have some fun with it and try

```
Select 5 + '4.0'
```

Comment: it's strange sql server doesn't do this. change 5 to 5.0 and see.